# How to bypass iMac 2015 Firmware Password?

Tags: imac, recovery, firmware

first of all, I apologize for my bad english
I have a question and I will be really happy if someone can help me.
A while ago I bought an imac from 2015 as used ( so I don`t have any invoice) but lately I miss some speed and because of this I decided to upgrade HDD to SSD. When I did it and wanted to do a clean install, I got a padlock on the screen, "So frimware password", and I don't have this one.
I tried to go to recovery mode via Command + R, but when I pressed that, it asks again for the password.
boot via USB failed.
NVRM reset failed
memory replacement, not helped

Does anyone have any idea about this ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do besides taking in Macbook to remove firmware password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190485/what-can-i-do-besides-taking-in-macbook-to-remove-firmware-password) Only Apple can unlock it, & they will require proof of ownership. The RAM trick only worked on pre2011 Macs.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you have no alternative to contacting the former owner in order to have the information or at least to recover an invoice to ask Apple to intervene.